# Webpack 3 + PostCSS does not hotloading when changed css file of @import

Tags: webpack, postcss, webpack-3, postcss-import

Here is my css webpack config

`{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'style-loader',
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: { sourceMap: true, importLoaders: 1 }
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        // https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/92
        // https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/8
        plugins: () => [
          precss(),
          postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webpack }),
          postcssNested(),
          postcssCssnext({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9'],
            compress: true,
          }),
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}`

And I'm using Webpack 3, the hotloading feature doesn't work if I touch a css file that is an @import, people suggesed me to put `postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webpack })` to the first line of the plugin, but if I put before the precss, I got an compilation error.

[image]

I wonder if there is anything wrong with the above config, any help is appreciated.

You can reproduce the issue in this repo

https://github.com/iroy2000/react-redux-boilerplate .

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I need to do two things

1) `postcssImport({ addDependencyTo: webpack })` need to be first in the plugin

2) I was trying to use `sass @import style` for my partial, but it turns out I need to include `_` when I import my partials.

And this solved my issues.